# java.lang.Long cannot be cast to java.lang.String in Java

Tags: java, casting

I'm getting response in this manner:

```
[{Id=1066276530, Key1=1815401000238}, {Id=1059632250, Key1=1815401000244}]
```

When I iterate and convert the values into a string, it throws me the error:

```
java.lang.Long cannot be cast to java.lang.String in Java

 for (Map<String, String> map : leadIds) {
        for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : map.entrySet()) {
            String applicationNumber = (String) entry.getValue();
        }
}
```

I want to convert the value into a string. Is there any issue here?

Comment: It seems that you have coerced the generics in order to force the compiler to think you have a `Map<String, String>` when you have a `Map<String, Long>`. Please show the declaration of `leadIds`.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Use `String.valueOf()` instead of casting:

```
for (Map<String, Long> map : leadIds) {
        for (Map.Entry<String, Long> entry : map.entrySet()) {
            String applicationNumber = String.valueOf(entry.getValue());
        }
}
```

Comment: `Entry<String, String>` already has `getValue` as a `String`. No amount of adding arbitrary `toString` calls will change that. The issue is with the generics.

Comment: Ok, I know your issue. Could you up the code which process the input data?

Answer (score 5):

Because `String` and `Long` are completely different types you cannot cast them, but you can use static method `String.valueOf(Long value)` and backwards `Long.valueOf(String value)`.